# Export from OneNote 2007 to Word and retain outline styles

Tags: microsoft-word, export, microsoft-onenote-2007

OneNote 2007 has the ability to export to Microsoft Word (File | Send To | Microsoft Office Word); however, I'm looking for a way to export to Microsoft Word and retain the outline levels so that it can be easily formatted with Word styles rather than having to manually set the outline levels in Word Outline mode after exporting.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way of doing this. OneNote converts the idented OneNote outline into Word paragraph idents. You'd have to do some clever search and replace looking for particular idents (find, format, paragraph, indentation) with heading 3 style (format, paragraph, heading 3).